# Regarding multiple ajax request for same function

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, jquery

**My Aim:**

To get response from ajax and show response from ajax as "First come first serve basis".

Technology: ruby on rails + ajax (javascript)

**Explanation:**

1. In image below 5 request are shown. 1st and 2nd request is re-run with same 4th and 5th request.
   Third request should Ideally take time all other request should take less than a second.
   I wish to get response from server via ajax independent of request sent.

In sort,  *If 3rd request complete in 4.49 second and 5th request take  0.5 second. 5th Request should not wait for third request. Is it possible ? How?*

Kindly help me !

[image: multiple ajax request]

Comment: Your wording is throwing me off... asynchronous request don't wait for other requests (thus the 'asynchronous' in the name) if that's what you're asking. It is innately first come first serve.

Comment: Joseph, It is waiting when requested for same `method execution`. I am sure for this.

Comment: I think in his case he can only process one request per time on his localhost server. If this is running on a production server it should behave differently.

Comment: I am using `POST` method for ajax. It may be due to ruby on rails would waiting to complete one request. I really don't know :(

Comment: @ror_master, what you are seeing may be an artifact of how your Ruby application is responding to your AJAX calls.  on the JavaScript end of an AJAX request, the method calls are totally independent and return data independently.  But your Ruby application may be processing requests FIFO, thus causing the apparent latency on the JavaScript side.

Comment: @RossSmith , You may be right. But, I has to have a solution. Perhaps, I will have to go deeper how ruby handle server requests?

Comment: Perhaps, I am not a Ruby dev - looks like Thorsten has you covered though :) Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

From the [Ruby 1.9.x Web Servers Booklet](http://www.scribd.com/doc/20755982/23/WEBrick)

WEBrick is implemented as a single process multi threaded server. Nothing prevents you from starting several WEBricks, each listening on its own port and load balancing between them via and external load balancer. But the server itself does not provide any multiprocessing features of its own.

If you want to process several requests in parallel, you may need to chose a different server or server setup.

Comment: Thanks thorsten, I need a favor! If you can suggest me any tutorial to handle such situation in ruby (means server setting on live) or what different server?

Comment: @ror_master: I'm not sure about development mode, but I think Phusion Passenger would be worth to look at, though the correct setup may be a challenge.

Comment: Ok, I will check that with Phusion Passenger on live..Thanks again.

Comment: I found [a link here](http://modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#PassengerSpawnMethod) It could help me, I will check and let know here .